# Проект установки надстройки MS Excel 2007

Tags: c#, vsto

Создал надстройку для MS Excel 2007 (VS 2008 \ C# \ VSTO). Теперь не выходит создать проект установки (Setup) - MS Excel 2007 в упор не видит надстройку. Естественно, если запускать файл vsto или в режиме разработки - все работает, но хочется использовать стандартный установщик. Скорей всего, требуется в проекте установки задать ключи реестра для надстройки. Подскажите, у кого есть опыт по данной тематике.

Answer (score 1):

Если интересно, то разобрался:
 1. Microsoft, как всегда, все запутала, и в проекте Setup необходимо править параметры реестра для надстройки (парадокс, но стандартные параметры необходимо удалять и создавать свои, согласно MSDN).
 2. Очень важно обеспечить переопределение событий MS Office (внедрение своих), знакомый механизм делегатов - за эту возможность Microsoft спасибо.
 3. Вообще, создать бизнес-приложение с использованием C#, MS Office AddIn и, тем более, учитывая уровень пользователей, - экономия времени и денег.